# Cannot retrieve renamed attribute's value in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my iOS app's core data model, I had an **Entity** called `Fish` with a string **attribute** called `mainText`. I renamed this attribute to `questionText`. The CRUD operations works fine for the new data. However, I cannot read the old data, the one written when the attribute was called `mainText`. Here is what I have tried:

1. Renaming it back to `mainText`, it does not work.
2. Adding a new attribute called like the old one, `mainText`, it does not work.

How would you proceed to retrieve the old data's values (the one wrote when the attribute was still called `mainText`) ?

Comment: altering core data structure needs to be addressed with core data migration.

Comment: Did you release your app to users with the renamed attribute, and did this cause them to lose data?

Comment: @Mike Taverne: No, the version on the AppStore works fine with the old data model. The unpublished new version has the modified data model.

Comment: Did you have your data model under source control? You should roll back to the data model as it existed prior to the rename.

Comment: @MikeTaverne, I managed to do it manually and make the old data work. Don't know why but Xcode's version editor window behaves funny with CoreData files under version control. Now going for a lightweight migration thanks to Praveen Kumar's comment. When all works, I post an answer to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to rename an attribute and keep the old data, there are two things you need to do:

1. Create a new version of the data model. You probably already did this, or your app would not have been able to load the old data at all. If not though, make sure you keep your changes in a different version of the model file. The old model version needs to be available or migration won't work.
2. On this property, set the "renaming identifier" field to contain the old name of the attribute. This will tell Core Data that it should migrate values to the new attribute name. Without that it can't tell if you want to rename the attribute or if you want to delete the old one and add a new, different attribute. In the model editor, you'll find this on the right when you select the new attribute:

[image: Renaming ID]

You may find Apple's [guide to lightweight migration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/using_lightweight_migration) to be useful too.